# REST Fetching data with GET not possible due to exceed header size limit

Tags: api, rest, post, get

I am having a dilema. I need to fetch data for some products by Id, these products which are selected can vary from a couple to thousands.

I see and tested that `GET` is not possible due to exceeding the `HeaderSizeLimit` of 8192.

I had discussions with colleagues and changed to `POST` and the ids are in the body. Everything works but have a lot of discussions about this. Have you encountered something like this? What was your approach?

Answer (score 0):

First question for me is, do you really pass all those ids in a single request? How is this list of IDs generated in the first place? Could the server know this list in advance?

For example, if the list of IDs is obtained by doing a search query on the same server, perhaps that search query can already emit the list of entities.

I find that in *most* cases this can be avoided, but there's some exceptions.

If you find that you can't avoid this, I would suggest you use the new http `QUERY` method instead of of `POST`, but `POST` should be fine too as a fallback.

Comment: Well I get in FrontEnd a list of ids (can be any number), then you can select any number or combination of ids. The server doesn't know which until it gets the request from FrontEnd. I went with the POST and the id's inside body, will look into QUERY in the future as I've not used it until now.